# Java Regex match first occurrence of dot

Tags: java, regex

In this string:
jdbc:sqlserver://testserver.apple.com\A4534:54623

I want to match "testserver" "apple.com//A4534" and "54623"

Regex:
 `jdbc:sqlserver:(.+)\.(.+):(.+)`

But I get,
"testserver.apple" "com//A4534" and "54623"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following regex:

```
jdbc:sqlserver:\/\/(\w+).(.+):(\w+)
```

**Explanation:**

1. `\/` specifies the `/`
2. `\w+` specifies word character i.e. `[A-Za-z0-9_]+`

Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/VlVxCd/1) for a demo.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = " jdbc:sqlserver://testserver.apple.com\\A4534:54623";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("jdbc:sqlserver:\\/\\/(\\w+).(.+):(\\w+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + "\n" + matcher.group(2) + "\n" + matcher.group(3));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
testserver
apple.com\A4534
54623
```